# Atualização App android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, apk

Olá,

Sou novo no desenvolvimento android e estou com algumas duvidas, estou desenvolvendo um APK utilizando um webview e frequentemente estou atualizando ele com algumas melhorias. Como eu trabalho a mais de 200km de onde estão os tablets com o APK intalados, gostaria de fazer com que o APK vitrificasse se tem uma nova versão e atualizar automaticamente caso tenha uma nova versão.

Isso é possível? Poderiam me explicar como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um serviço para verificar isso e avisar o usuário, mas tenho uma opção melhor, normalmente os dispositivos android tem como ativar verificação de atualização automática, dessa forma quando você soltar uma nova versão na Play Store ele iria atualizar sozinho se estivesse conectado a internet.

Passos para fazer como falei:
Para atualizar apps automaticamente no seu dispositivo Android:

1. Abra o app Google Play Store Google Play.
2. Toque em Menu Menu depois Configurações.
3. Toque em Atualizar apps automaticamente.
4. Selecione uma opção:

   - Atualizar apps automat. a qualquer hora para atualizar apps usando dados da rede celular ou Wi-Fi.
   - Atualizar apps automaticamente somente via Wi-Fi para atualizar apps somente quando o dispositivo estiver conectado a uma rede Wi-Fi.
     Observação: se uma conta no seu dispositivo apresentar um erro de login, os apps não serão atualizados automaticamente.

De uma olhada [aqui](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=pt-BR) para mais informações!